# Prove that there do not exist distinct reals $x,y,u,v$ such that $x^2+y^2=u^2+v^2 , x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3$ simultaneously hold.

Tags: calculus

Prove that there do not exist distinct reals $x,y,u,v$ such that $x^2+y^2=u^2+v^2 , x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3$ simultaneously hold.
I was wondering if I convert the two relations into a single relation and then look at it as the quadratic of $x$
But the process is quite tedious and may not be useful.
Help.

Comment: It is hard to prove something that is not true.

Comment: Give counterexample if you think it is wrong

Comment: Both answers give the same one. but the approach looks like it can give as many as we want.

Answer (score 5):

$x=1$

$y=2$

$u=-\frac 34+\frac 14\sqrt{33}+\frac 14\sqrt{-2+6\sqrt{33}}\approx 2.110644432 $

$v = -\frac 4{11}u^3-\frac 6{11}u^2+u+3\approx -0.738363107$

And $x^2+y^2=u^2+v^2$ and $x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3$, I used a CAS to do this, but certainly it has real solutions.

---

Here is another idea to find some "not too complicated" solutions.

Let's have $\begin{cases} x=\cos(\theta_1) & u=\cos(\theta_2) \\y=\sin(\theta_1) & v=\sin(\theta_2)\end{cases}$

Obviously $x^2+y^2=u^2+v^2=1$

Let's try to search for multiple points of $\cos(\theta)^3+\sin(\theta)^3=k$

Converting to $t=\tan(\theta/2)$

we get $f(t)=\dfrac{(1-3t^2+3t^4-t^6+8t^3)}{(1+t^2)^3}=k$

[image]

From the graph, we can see that for $k\in[-1,1]$, there are always at least two values such that $f(t)=k$, the purpose is to try to find the "easy" ones, I mean these with not too complicated algebraic expression.

- $k=1$ is the simplest, and gives real solutions $0$ and $1$, unfortunately this leads to $\theta=0,\frac \pi2$ and the unique value $(0,1)$ for both $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$.
- $k=0$ is also simple, and gives real solutions $1\pm\sqrt{2}$, unfortunately this leads to $\theta=\frac {3\pi}4,-\frac{\pi}4$ and again to an unique value $(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}2,\frac{\sqrt{2}}2)$.
- $k=-1$ leads to $t=-1,\pm\infty$ with $\theta=-\frac\pi2,\pm\pi$ and again the unique solution $(-1,0)$.

So I experimented with some rational values of $k$ that would lead to a nice factorization of $f(t)-k$:

- $k=\frac {11}{16}\quad$ gives $t=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{7}}3\quad$ but just one solution $(-0.4114378275,0.9114378279)$
- $k=\frac {13}{27}\quad$ gives $t=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{17}}4\quad$ but just one solution $(-0.5205176048,0.8538509373)$

Unfortunately these kind of "conjugated" $\theta=2\arctan(\frac{a\pm\sqrt{b}}c)$ seem to lead to an unique value the two couples $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$.

In fact I have noticed the fact below (it is only experimental figures, not a proof):

For a value of $|k|<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2$ there are two solutions in $t$ and they give an unique solution in $(x,y)$ while in the other region we have four solutions in $t$, two of them are conjugated and give the same solution in $(x,y)$, but if we take one $t$ in each pair of conjugated solutions we end up with two valid couples $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$.

Example:

- $k=\frac {22}{27}\quad$ gives $t=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{2}}7$ and $t=-\frac3{14}+\frac 3{14}\sqrt{15}\pm\frac 1{14}\sqrt{-136+66\sqrt{15}}\quad$ giving $(x,y)=(0.4309644061,0.9023689271)$ and $(u,v)=(0.9466350923,-0.3223073100)$

I have experimented all the values for $k$ with denominator $\le 2000$ but did not found a factorization of $f(t)-k$ into three quadratics.

There was always one irreducible polynomial of degree $4$, so it is not much simpler than solving directly for $x=1,y=2$ as what was done in the first example.

Anyway, this study suggests that for $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2<|k|<1$ there would be always four solutions in $t$, two of them giving two couple of different solutions in $(x,y)$ leading to an infinity of solutions of the original problem, but I did not searched to prove it.

Comment: maple code $\to$ https://bpaste.net/show/3f38f4208788

Answer (score 3):

For $x=1$ and $y=2$ we obtain, using the Buchberger algorithm,
$$
u=\frac{1}{11}( - 4v^3 - 6v^2 + 11v + 33),
$$
where $v$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
f(t)=2t^4 + 6t^3 - t^2 - 33t - 22.
$$
This has two real solutions, namely $v=2.11064443223$, and
$v= - 0.738363108965$.

The methods also works for other given values of $x$ and $y$. There are infinitely many real solutions $(x,y,u,v)$ with distinct $x,y,u,v$.

Comment: Show us your $4$ distinct reals!

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $(x,y,u,v)=(1,2,-0.738363108965,2.11064443223)$ as given in the answer! Compare with the other answer (of course, one can take other initial values for $x$ and $y$)

Answer (score 0):

One more solution
$$
x=6,\\
y=10,\\
u=-4+3\,\sqrt {6}-\sqrt {-2+24\,\sqrt {6}},\\
v=-4+3\,\sqrt {6}+\sqrt {-2+24\,\sqrt {6}} .
$$